# javascript not giving result

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to build one form in which submit button compares typed value with the already entered value  and if it is correct it gives answer as correct and put 1 in number field.here answer is ok but it is not displaying 1 in marks field My code is

```
<script>
 function marks()
          {    
             var marks="<?php echo $marks; ?>";
             document.getElementById('marks').value = marks;
          }
        </script>
 

<h1>Identify the Sound</h1> 
    
<table name="tb" class="table table-bordered"  id="tb">   
    <tr>
        <th  width=10%;>Audio Clip</th>
        <th  width=10%;></th>
        <th width=10%;>Type your answer</th>
        <th width=30%;></th>
        <th width=10%;>Marks</th>
    </tr>
    <form action="" method="POST">                          
<tr>
 
<td><audio width=10%; controls preload="none">
  <source src="emer.wav" type="audio/wav">   
</audio>
</td>
<td><input width=10%;  name="name1" value="siron" class="form-control" type="hidden" ></td>
<td><input width=20%; type="text" name="compare1" class="form-control" style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:30px; height:35px;font-weight:bold"></td>
<td><button width=20%;type="submit" onClick="marks()" name="submit1" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:30px; height:35px; font-weight:bold" class="form-control">Submit Answer </button> <span >
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
 $name1=$_POST['name1'];
  $compare1=$_POST['compare1'];

    $value= strcasecmp("$name1","$compare1");

 if ($value==0){
     echo "Correct Answer";
     $marks=1;
 }else{
     echo "wrong answer";
     $marks=0;
 }
}
?>
</span></td>
<td><input width=20%; type="number" name="marks" id="marks" class="form-control" style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:30px; height:35px;font-weight:bold"></td>
</tr>
</form>

</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a pure browser-side problem (as the markup is generated properly, but executed wrong), or one involving the server?

Comment: I think i m doing somthing wron in js

Comment: Can you explain that further? If this is a pure JS problem, please edit your question to contain the generated markup triggering the problem

Comment: Where is the marks function? If it's in a different file, PHP isn't going to define the value. Edit: Move the marks function into a `<script>` tag with the rest of the HTML.

Comment: @ can u explain more

Comment: I assume that your HTML is in a PHP file but your JavaScript is in a JS file. PHP will generate the HTML properly but will not do anything for the JS file. If I understand the issue, you can move the JS into the PHP file, and it will pick up.

Comment: @DeanJames if you dont minfdcan u edit my code

Comment: Move the `<script>` block after the `</table>`.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue where PHP is preventing the JavaScript from running due to the form submit:

1. PHP loads the file and generates the HTML.
2. User submits the answer form.
3. The form is submitted to the server and the JavaScript has no chance of running.
4. The PHP renders the same empty fields like before, because JavaScript has not populated the fields.

I suggest removing JavaScript from this completely and have PHP populate the value of the marks fields instead:

```
<td><input value="<?php echo $marks; ?>" width=20%; type="number" name="marks" id="marks" class="form-control" style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:30px; height:35px;font-weight:bold"></td>
```

Comment: But it will not genrate the value on the click .

Comment: The value does not have to be generated on click, it is generated by the POST and reload of the page.